# structKeyExists with XML Data Does Not Work

Tags: coldfusion

I am working with the below XML feed and am using structKeyExists and CFLoop to display the data it contains.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfxml variable="eating">
<catalog>
<results>10    </results>
<food id="bk101">
<initials type="thefirst" name="BK"/>
<initials type="thesecond" name="KB"/>
<keywords>Burger King, pie, hamburgers, fries, milkshakes    </keywords>
</food>
<food id="bk102">
<initials type="thefirst" name="TB"/>
<initials type="thesecond" name="BT"/>
<keywords>Taco Bell, tacos, churros, burrito, gorditas    </keywords>
</food>
<food id="bk103">
<keywords>Pizza Hut, pizza, cheese, garlic bread    </keywords>
</food>
<food id="bk104">
<initials type="thefirst" name="CFA"/>
<initials type="thesecond" name="AFC"/>
<keywords>Chick-Fil-A, chicken, chicken wrap, sauce, Bananas Pudding Milkshake    </keywords>
</food>
<food id="bk105">
<initials type="thefirst" name="PE"/>
<initials type="thesecond" name="EP"/>
<keywords>Panda Express, rice, egg rolls, general tso    </keywords>
</food>
<food id="bk106">
<initials type="thefirst" name="SJ"/>
<initials type="thesecond" name="JS"/>
<keywords>Sakura Japan, rice, spring rolls, bento    </keywords>
</food>
<food id="bk107">
<initials type="thefirst" name="FG"/>
<keywords>Five Guys, fries, burgers, hot dogs    </keywords>
</food>
<food id="bk108">
<initials type="thefirst" name="TN"/>
<initials type="thesecond" name="NT"/>
<keywords>Tandoori Nights, biryani, chicken, egg rolls    </keywords>
</food>
<food id="bk109">
<initials type="thefirst" name="HoK"/>
<keywords>House of Kabob, rice, bread, beef kabaob, chicken kabob    </keywords>
</food>
<food id="bk110">
<initials type="thefirst" name="BF"/>
<initials type="thesecond" name="FB"/>
<keywords>Baja Fresh, quesadilla, soft taco, chili con queso    </keywords>
</food>
</catalog>
</cfxml>
</cfoutput>

<cfset data = queryNew("id,initials,initials2,keywords","integer,varchar,varchar,varchar")>

<cfloop index="x" from="1" to="#eating.catalog.results.xmlText#">
    <cfif structKeyExists(eating.catalog.food[x],"initials")>
        <cfset queryAddRow(data)>
        <cfset querySetCell(data,"id",x)>
        <cfset querySetCell(data,"initials", eating.catalog.food[x].initials[1].xmlattributes.name )>
        <cfset querySetCell(data,"initials2", eating.catalog.food[x].initials[2].xmlattributes.name )>
        <cfset querySetCell(data,"keywords", eating.catalog.food[x].keywords )>
     </cfif>

</cfloop>

<cfoutput query="data">
#id# - #initials# :: #initials2# :: #keywords#  <br /><br />
</cfoutput>
```

You will notice there is one initial tag missing for Element 3 and two that are missing for Elements 7 and 9 in the XML feed . If the initials tags are added to the XML for Elements 3,7,9, the code works beautifully. However since they are missing, this causes an error to be thrown out an error.

What I would like to do is omit Element 3 (and all other entries which cause an error) from my results and prevent any errors from showing so the application result shows up like so:

1 - BK :: KB :: Burger King, pie, hamburgers, fries, milkshakes

2 - TB :: BT :: Taco Bell, tacos, churros, burrito, gorditas

4 - CFA :: AFC :: Chick-Fil-A, chicken, chicken wrap, sauce, Bananas Pudding Milkshake

5 - PE :: EP :: Panda Express, rice, egg rolls, general tso

6 - SJ :: JS :: Sakura Japan, rice, spring rolls, bento

8 - TN :: NT :: Tandoori Nights, biryani, chicken, egg rolls

10 - BF :: FB :: Baja Fresh, quesadilla, soft taco, chili con queso

Note my example is simplified, in actuality I am working with an XML feed with hundreds of elements. With that in mind, what am I doing wrong and how can I get the above to display correctly?

Comment: It does work. However your extra requirements exceed what `structKeyExists` is designed to do :) structKeyExists only tells you if the specified key (or node name) exists, nothing more. If you *also* want to verify the number of elements, you need to use array functions too as Busches mentioned.

Comment: .. and you might also want to review [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbb.html) to get a better understanding of what the various functions do/don't do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StructKeyExists() works just fine, but you need to check to ensure the second initials exists too. Adding ArrayLen(eating.catalog.food[x].initials) GT 1 (or EQ 2, if you know it'll always be 2) will solve it.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(eating.catalog.food[x],"initials") AND ArrayLen(eating.catalog.food[x].initials) GT 1>
```

With this fix, the example you gave outputs 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, and 10. If you want to print 7 and 9, just move the check to here:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(eating.catalog.food[x],"initials")>
    <cfset queryAddRow(data)>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"id",x)>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"initials", eating.catalog.food[x].initials[1].xmlattributes.name )>
    <cfif ArrayLen(eating.catalog.food[x].initials) GT 1>
        <cfset querySetCell(data,"initials2", eating.catalog.food[x].initials[2].xmlattributes.name )>
    </cfif>
    <cfset querySetCell(data,"keywords", eating.catalog.food[x].keywords )>
 </cfif>
```

Comment: YES!!! It worked!! Thank you!! I spent hours pulling my hair today trying different things to get this to work. Finally, I have finished my first ColdFusion application with of course thanks so much to you Busches and craig.kaminsky, and Paul from Stackoverflow! i can finally go home!!!